# Session lost after header redirect

Tags: php, session

I have two pages:

- page1.php
- doLogin.php

page1 has a button to doLogin.php with the social platform where the login has to be done.

```
Button 1: doLogin.php?social=twitter 
Button 2: doLogin.php?social=instagram
```

The doLogin page is something like:

```
session_start();
if($_REQUEST['social'] == 'twitter') {
$user->auth('twitter');
}

if($_REQUEST['social'] == 'instagram') {
$user->auth('instagram');
}

header('Location: page1.php');
exit();
```

The auth() method saves the username in the session. If I do a var_dump of the session before the redirect I get all the data correctly. Example:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
die();
header('Location: page1.php');
exit();
```

If I do a var_dump and a die at the very beginning of page1.php after the login for instagram has been done the session is empty. If the login is with twitter the session data is kept. Example:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION);
die();
```

Comment: did you do session_start() at the page beginning of the pag1.php file?

Comment: Have you defined `session_start` in `page1.php`?

Comment: are you doing this on localhost? twitter will redirect to `127.0.0.1` and maybe instagram will redirect to `localhost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the header redirect inside an if statement that wasn't followed by an exit function. ALWAYS use the exit statement after an header redirect, otherwise the whole php page will be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Check Redirect URL. are redirecting to same URL? 
always use session_start() before using session.

Session registration on http://localhost is different than http://127.0.0.1.